# ODBC Transasaction in .Net connecting to PostGresQL Database. Insert not showing when inside a Transaction

Tags: c#, vb.net, postgresql, transactions, odbc

The insert function is working when not wrapped around a ODBC Transaction.

I attempted two methods when doing the insert. Currval and Returning (available in PostgreSQL 8.1 above)

```
  ''Dim sql As String = String.Format("Insert into barcodes Values (default, {0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'); Select currval ('barcodes_barcode_id_seq');",
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("Insert into barcodes Values (default, {0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}') Returning barcode_id",
```

I use the ExecuteScaler function to return the values using ODBC.

The new barcode_id is returned fine.

Continue on with my transaction. insert sales Records etc using this barcode id.

Commit transaction. Everything is committed but my barcodes table is Empty.

Take it out of Transaction and barcodes table is populating but as I need it.

Anyone got any ideas why it is not showing

Comment: Out of curiosity, why ODBC and not Npgsql?

Answer (score 0):

Caveat:  I don't know VB.net that well at all, and I did not use ODBC, but I am hopeful this will be directionally helpful for you.  If there is a compelling reason to use ODBC and not Npgsql, let me know.

First of all, assume the following object class that is populated:

```
public class Barcode
{
    public int BarcodeId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode1 { get; set; }
    public string Barcode2 { get; set; }
    public string Barcode3 { get; set; }
    public string Barcode4 { get; set; }
    public string Barcode5 { get; set; }
    public string Barcode6 { get; set; }
}
```

The following code would take a list of `Barcode` objects, insert them and populate the `BarcodeId` property with the result from the database:

```
string sql = @"
    insert into barcodes
    values (default, :B1, :B2, :B3, :B4, :B5, :B6)
    returning barcode_id
";

NpgsqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn, trans);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("B1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("B2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("B3", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("B4", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("B5", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("B6", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));

foreach (Barcode b in barcodes)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = b.Barcode1;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = b.Barcode2;
    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = b.Barcode3;
    cmd.Parameters[3].Value = b.Barcode4;
    cmd.Parameters[4].Value = b.Barcode5;
    cmd.Parameters[5].Value = b.Barcode6;

    b.BarcodeId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}

trans.Commit();
```